# How to store data from method after calling it?

Tags: java

I'm trying to store the data in a variable in the CongressStats that I fetched from the printPartyBreakdownInSenate method without "capturing" it and returning the value somehow.

```
public class CongressStats
{
private int congressNum;

public void printPartyBreakdownInSenate() {
     CongressDataFetcher.fetchSenateData(congressNum);
 }
```

here is the method I calling from.

```
public static String fetchSenateData(int congressNum)
{
    return fetchCongressData(Chamber.SENATE, congressNum);
}
```

Comment: Where are you storing returned value of fetchSenateData method?

Comment: nowhere, that's why I'm calling the method in the CongressStats class and attempting to store the data/value there.

Comment: you need to assign returned value to some class level variable, which u can use afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a String field below your congressNum field: `private String senateData;`

Then inside your `printPartyBreakdownInSenate` method do:

```
senateData = CongressDataFetcher.fetchSenateData(congressNum);
```

This will temporally store the String returned from the `fetchSenateData` method.  It will save the data until senateData is set to something else or until the program is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private String senateData;
public void printPartyBreakdownInSenate() {
   senateData = CongressDataFetcher.fetchSenateData(congressNum);
}
```

This is directly assigning the return value of the method you are calling to the `senateData` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a private variable in CongressStats and assign returned value to that variable and you can declare getter method to use that value outside that class.